# Setting fetchOnServer based on url parameter

Tags: nuxt.js

Is it possible to set fetchOnServer based on a URL parameter? e.g. if URL has ?renderonserver=true, use fetchOnServer: true.

Update:

Let me explain it further:

I've two URLs like /myview?renderonserver=true, /myview?renderonserver=false,

and the code looks like:

```js
export default {
  async fetch() {
    this.posts = await this.$http.$get(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'
    )
  },
  fetchOnServer: true
}
```

It is possible for the same view to change fetchOnServer based on what is used in the URL parameters? (on the first load of the page each time).

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand your doubt. Can you provide us more informations about that?

Comment: Apologies, let me explain it further: (made an update on the initial post)

Comment: well, in this case maybe you can use some thing like this: fetchOnServer: this.$route.params.renderonserver || false